# The keychain password changes automatically without changing account password

Tags: keychain

We have several Macbooks and regularly the keychain passwords have changed without the user changing the account password.  This causes problems because the applications no longer work.

What causes that keychain password to change?

Comment: Do you use any Mobile Device Management or remote backup software software?

Comment: Neither is used.

Comment: Do you use iCloud Keychain? What macOS version are you running?

Comment: What makes you think it has "changed"?  "Changed" to what?

Comment: By default keychain password is same as users password. So it has been changed if it does not accept users password.

Comment: Keychain is local. It is happening on High Sierra, Mojave and Catalina.